# Subscribing to Angular Observable returns Empty Array Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

---

**TL;DR; How do I get the Role[] array from the Observable into my Menu Editor component?**

---

I've spent hours googling on this. This should be a piece of cake in my head, but I just want to understand the behaviour here so I can avoid this problem in future. (I've stripped out as much code as possible to simplify things)

I have a menu editor component (the parent component) it iterates over my list of menu items, injecting the menu item into the menu editor child component as `menuItem`. In the child component I will have a form where the user can edit the menu item with. In the child form, I need an array of Roles within the application so I can create a check box list of them to pick from.

To achieve this i created a Role Service, and I can call the API etc. Everything here is working.

I then Inject the Role Service into the menu item editor, and I can subscribe to and iterate `*ngFor` over the Role Service's `roles` Observable. Fine.

I want to place the array of roles into the component.ts for the editor, so that I can start to build Reactive Forms. However, when I subscribe to the observable from the Role Service, it is empty.

When I try to `console.log()` inside the subscribe method, it does something very strang in the log. (Photo Attached).

There are 14 menu editor items drawn (plus 1 for the "add new") But i get 30 console log messages, and the first 15 are empty the second 15 have values.

**role.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleService {
  private roleSubject: BehaviorSubject<Role[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  roles: Observable<Role[]> = this.roleSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getAllRoles().subscribe();
   }

  getAllRoles() {
    return this.http.get<Role[]>(`${environment.privateApiUrl}/Role/Get`).pipe(
      map(data => {
        this.roleSubject.next(data)
      }),
      catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
        console.log(error);
        return of(result as T);
      })
    )
  }

}
```

**role.ts**

```
export class Role {
  id: number;
  roleName: string;
}
```

**menu-manager-item-edit.component.ts**

```
export class MenuManagerItemEditComponent implements OnInit {

  public roles: Role[] = [];
  @Input() public menuItem: SideMenuItem;

  constructor(public roleService: RoleService) {

    this.roleService.roles.subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.roles = response;
    })

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

[image: Console Output]

Comment: enjoy rxjs "expected" behaviour ;-). Lets say a couple of services subscribe to your observable. rxjs team be like "lets not make it default behavior to share same value across all subscriptions  Lets produce one value for each subscription" Took me a while to figure out that "feature"

Answer (score 0):

Propably you have multiplied subscribtion to your `Observable` 15 times so you get 15 times `console.log`. Why you get empty array and then array with `Roles`? Simple. You are using `BehaviorSubject` which store a value and everytime you subscribe to it, it initialy send the stored value. Thats why you need to set initial value. Once you pass `next` value, it notify every subscriber with new value. But remember whenever you subscribe, you will get last stored value.